# "Ready to connect when quality improves"

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-10

My Galaxy S10e shows near my home WiFi's name:

```
Ready to connect when quality improves
```

Even though the WiFi works very well (using it right now from laptop).

The phone has no cover, and no obstacle to the router which sits two meters away.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a manual proxy configured for this WiFi, and the proxy was not working correctly.

Removing the manual proxy configuration solved the problem.

To check if you have one, tap the WiFi, then tap "Advanced", then make sure "Proxy" is set to "None".